# Internal Domain but need to point subfolder to external with same name

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns

I have a domain name monster-it.uk which is used for internal use, however we own this external domain name too and have our webhosting billing system on it. But inside the domain in our office it redirects too the local DC,

Is there a way to create a DNS records so anyone inside going to say monster-it.uk/order/ goes outside to see the actual program?

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to install a reverse proxy server on your DC or configure IIS to act as a reverse proxy for your external server.

everything starting with the first slash in the URL is outside the scope of DNS and is handled directly by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an another domain, like this: external.monster-it.uk and this one "goes outside"